# Debian Tor Browser Showing a Black Screen

Tags: debian, tor

I’ve just moved from Stretch to Buster with a Cinnamon desktop. This more or less does everything I need except that I also load stable firefox (using snap), AirVPN and Tor from the buster-backport repository.

Normally there aren’t any problems except this time the Tor screen (after using the launcher) is black and unresponsive. I’ve done a clean install and then just installed Tor but the problem remains.

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer form Debian bugs tracker : bug [#942901](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942901)

edit your `/etc/apparmor.d/local/torbrowser.Browser.firefox` and add the following line:

```
owner /{dev,run}/shm/org.mozilla.*.* rw,
```

Also add exactly the same line to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/torbrowser.Browser.plugin-container`. Then:

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

The Debian bug tracker states:

> [Message #5](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942901#5)
>
> Tor Browser 9.0 shows only black screens because the default apparmor
>   profile does not allow write access to /dev/shm/org.mozilla.ipc.*.*
>   like it does for /dev/shm/org.chromium.* and I was able to fix this
>   issue by adding this workaround:
>
> ==> /etc/apparmor.d/local/torbrowser.Browser.firefox <==
>
> ```
> owner /{dev,run}/shm/org.mozilla.*.* rw,
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have solved that on my own. I'm seldom in the terminal. I've been using Debian for everyday computing for over a decade, first with Gnome and now with Cinnamon, and this is the first time that I've had any trouble that wasn't entirely my own fault.

Comment: I also had to do the same thing to `torbrowser.Browser.plugin-container` (in `/etc/apparmor.d/local`) !!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Parrot(based on debian testing)
Found out that unloading appArmor profiles by "aa-teardown" fixed the issue.